# Dynamically Decrypt a Referenced dll

Tags: c#, reference, encryption

I want to have a referenced dll in my Windows Forms Application project. It is imperative to me that the dll is encrypted at first, and later decrypted on runtime when it needs to be used.

Please consider the following example where a sub routine is originally encrypted, but then decrypted and instantiated. Note, this is a conceptual idea only, I have no clue as to how this needs to be done in terms of code.

```
Class clsSO
{
void myVoid()
{
Console.WriteLine("We are here now ...");
}
} // End class
```

The above code would be wrapped in a .dll and added as a referenced dll to my project. The dll would then be referenced and the sub routine called:

```
clsSo myRef = new clsSo();

myRef.myVoid();
```

**Console output reads:**

> We are here now...

**What I need to be done:**
The contents of the wrapper dll will be encrypted and thus unreadable / unable to reference the class directly. So, the dll will somehow need to be decrypted, and dynamically updated with the decrypted data so that I can then reference it.

Does something like this already exist? Can it even be done?

I appreciate the time everyone!

Thanks,

Evan

Comment: Quick question, as it will affect my answer. Why are you encrypting, to protect sensitive data or as a licensing method for the dll? Both are valid reasons but have different "best" solutions.

Comment: I want to protect the data inside. Much like an obfuscator does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to Call [Assembly.Load(Byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx) on the decrypted bytes of your file. once you have that you will need to either use reflection or cast the class to a interface so you can access the methods.

Here is a example

```
class Example
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] decryptedLibArray;
        using (var fs = new FileStream("clsSo.cDll", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (var aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        using (var aesTransform = aesProvider.CreateDecryptor(YourKey, YourIV))
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fs, aesTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            decryptedLibArray = ReadFully(cryptoStream);
        }

        var lib = Assembly.Load(decryptedLibArray);

        IclsSO classInstance = (IclsSO)lib.CreateInstance("clsSO"); //If you use a namespace this will be namespace.clsSO

        classInstance.myVoid();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads data from a stream until the end is reached. The
    /// data is returned as a byte array. An IOException is
    /// thrown if any of the underlying IO calls fail.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream to read data from</param>
    public static byte[] ReadFully (Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int read = stream.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (read <= 0)
                    return ms.ToArray();
                ms.Write (buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
}

interface IclsSO
{
    void myVoid();
}
```

`ReadFully` is from [this posting](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html). Read it to see why I did not just do `cryptoStream.Read(data, 0, decryptedLibArray.Length);` There are some errors with the final example but the memory stream example he gives is perfect.

However someone could just dump the ram of your program and get the decrypted binary, or possibly decompile your main program and get the decryption keys and just decrypt it themselves. So depending on how paranoid you are, you may still want to invest in a obfuscateor.

Comment: I'm going to take a look at this when I get home - this looks like an outstanding answer to my question though - thanks!